# Volume control using Core Audio

Tags: iphone, ios, core-audio, volume

I have been using this code to re-route the sound to speaker from microphone. I have been able to successfully do it using this [piece of code](https://code.google.com/p/ios-coreaudio-example/).
 but now I want to increase the volume the speaker that is coming from microphone. I have tried google it but not able to find out the solution. Can anybody help me in this?

Comment: I don't understand "I want to increase the volume the speaker that is coming from microphone". There is no speaker coming from the microphone. Do you want to increase the volume of the speaker on the device? As if you were pressing the volume-up button? Or do you want to increase the gain from the microphone?

Comment: yes, i want to increase the gain.

Comment: I have already solved this problem by multiplying  the output with the gain. and will post it as answer soon.

Comment: ok, and what is the answer?